# Pandas error when appending dataframes: invalid dtype determination in get_concat_dtype

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append, python-3.6

I have two `dataframes` with the same `dtypes`:

```
>>> df1.dtypes
Out[3]: 

GUID             object
RID               int64
SID               int64
Threshold       float64
Average         float64
dtype: object

>>> df2.dtypes
Out[4]: 

GUID           object
RID             int64
SID             int64
Threshold     float64
Average       float64
dtype: object
```

When running
`df1.append(df2)`
or
`pd.concat([df1,df2])`

I'm getting the following error:

```
in get_empty_dtype_and_na
    raise AssertionError("invalid dtype determination in get_concat_dtype")
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488417/solution-for-assertionerror-invalid-dtype-determination-in-get-concat-dtype-whe

Comment: I have no reason to think I have duplicate column names (see dtypes) nor is any df empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was MultiIndex

Using [droplevel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) fixed the issue.

Very confusing error message.

```
df1.columns.droplevel(1)
df1.append(df2)
```

Comment: Could you give your solution? I suspect I have something similar: some of my dataframes have columns that are MultiIndex, and others that are Index. However, in my attempts to use droplevel, I get either "Must pass non-zero number of levels/labels" or "Too many levels: Index has only 1 levels, not 2".

Comment: @bli its possible that your columns have all sorts of levels, they are not necassirily all in the same dimensions. when you print `df.dtypes` you can see the level depth by the indentations. if you take a look at my question, you'll see `df1` has one depth level more than `df2`, but it could also have been that only some columns had deeper levels